# Convert Varchar to DateTime - Varchar has no character to divide date parts

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to convert a varchar of 5122012 to a datetime of 05/12/2012?

Thanks

Comment: how would 05/01/2012 be in your database ? 512012 or 5012012 ?

Comment: What kind of sql server are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can't do it without trailing zeros of day and month. So your input data must be something like:

```
05122012
```

Second it is better to use the "native" format of:

```
20121205
```

what the server understands anyway

If it is the only way to get the data as you presented you would need a function to test and return the date

Basic function would be like this (SQL Server 2008 example):

This function works if the input data is: `05122012` if you need without trailing `0` you need to add the checks for that to the function

```
create function [dbo].[Str2Date] ( @data as varchar(8))
returns datetime
AS
begin
    declare @day char(2), @mon char(2), @year char(4)
    set @day = substring(@data,1,2)
    set @mon = substring(@data,3,2)
    set @year = substring(@data,5,4)
    set @data = @year+@mon+@day
    return convert (datetime,@data,112)
end

select dbo.Str2Date('05122012')
```